# Does Checking Firebase Custom Claims in Flutter every 10 Minutes Cost A Lot of Money for 10K Users?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, cost-management

I am using Firebase customClaim to check user's device id to prevent multi-devices use by one account. So I checked it using `getIdTokenResult()` for every 10 minutes. Now, I am worried if my app will have 10K users then the operational fee will be a lot. Does it really cost a lot? If it does, is there a way to cut down the cost? Thank you for helping me out.

```js
     await user!.getIdTokenResult(false).then((result) {
        if (result.claims!.isNotEmpty) {
            idClaim = "${result.claims!["id01"]}";
            if(idClaim == deviceID){
              //Do not logout!
            } else {
              //Logout automatically
            }
        } else {
          // Send error message
        }
     }
```

Comment: Where do you think the cost will come from here?

Comment: Checking customClaim?

Comment: Why do you think this check would cost anything at all, given what you see in the pricing documentation? https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Comment: I see now. So, it doesn't cost anything at all. Thank you for helping me out, @DougStevenson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cost incurred by Firebase for this code.  The [pricing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) is clear that Firebase Authentication is free to use except for certain operations.